# Taquito: Is it possible to create smart contract transactions and send them to a over the network without using the .send method?

Tags: taquito

I wonder if it's possible to create smart contract transactions and them send them to a over the network without using the `.send` method...? I need to group and sort and some things (from different users) before sending to an RPC / mempool

```
Create & sign -> Send to magic API -> Magic API does some stuff stuff -> RPC
```

Question from Asbjorn in Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [Local Forging Package](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/local_forger/) to forge a transaction locally, and send the signed bytes over to an intermediate server, which can later inject them via an RPC node.

For example, following Taquito's current documentation:

**Preparing a Transaction Operation**

```
import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito'

const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(RPC_URL);

// The PrepareProvider returns a 'PreparedOperation' type object
const prepared = await Tezos.prepare.transaction({
  source: SOURCE_PKH,
  to: DESTINATION_PKH,
  amount: 5
});

// The PreparedOperation type object needs to be converted into a forgeable type (ForgeParams)
const forgeable = await Tezos.prepare.toForge(prepared);
```

**Forging the Transaction Operation**

```
const forger = new LocalForger();
const forgedBytes = await forger.forge(forgeable);
```

**Signing the Operation**

After the transaction operation has been forged, it can be signed as such:

```
const signed = await Tezos.signer.sign(forgedBytes, new Uint8Array([3]))
```

The `signed` bytes can then transmitted to an intermediate server, via some API made for that purpose.

The server can then inject the operation into the blockchain.

**Injecting the Operation**

```
const op = await Tezos.rpc.injectOperation(signed.sbytes);
```